# Diagnosing Bootstrap 3 Glyphicon Button Icons Not Showing

Tags: internet-explorer, bootstrap

I have a glyphicons in Bootstrap 3. They work very nicely here:

- latest Chrome
- latest Firefox
- latest Safari
- latest Explorer
- latest Android

At one facility, the glyphicons don't show. The buttons come up blank. How do I troubleshoot?

They are security sensitive there. I don't have systems or network access.. and am not in a position to request that.  Troubleshooting with advanced tools isn't going to happen. Here's what I have access to:

- Internet Explorer 9
- Behind a very secure firewall

Sometimes, I think the glyphs not showing is the IE 9.. but my code should be addressing that.

Sometimes, I think their firewall is blocking the CDN. Can I enter a URL into a browser to test if the CDN is there?

Sometimes, I think my FB share and like buttons upset this facilty's firewall, and they tie the whole thing down.

Any suggestions at how I begin to research this? Or maybe you have an outright idea for IE 9 and glyphs (though my code is very-very close to the demo's which work).

**UPDATE:** I never did solve the problem of getting glyphs to render. However, out of deadline driven desperation I did do a successful workaround: I switched to [Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/). FA works as desired, though I like the Glyph graphic design better.

Comment: I'm in the same situation with IE9. I have localhost and a staging site setup and the glyphicons work over both using http but not https. Maybe IE9 has a default security setting for https which blocks font-face?

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify that all works consistently when it's not inside their network? If so, you can at least start to make it their internal IT dept's problem. They have the ability to look at logs and test ports.

Presuming it's working on your side, I would start by using the F12 tools in IE while looking at their site. It will show you when assets are being requested and not loaded.

You can remove the CDN dependency entirely by downloading and including the glyphicons locally.

And yes, those FB share/like buttons can be promiscuous. You can in IE to see if they're causing problems.

Comment: Thanks Will.. I'm not a Explorer guy, so the F12 was good tip, will check tomorrow when I am there.  ...and yes: all works when not on their network, with caveat: I don't know how to check IE9.. how do you check an ancient browser... it's not like I have Vista loaded any where.

Comment: Sure, hope it helps. I do not miss the situation you're in right now! You can download virtual machines with older versions of IE from http://modern.ie/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work with IE as I haven't tried it. But I had glyphicons working on site locally, (in Firefox) but not when uploaded to live site.

I did a search on my computer for glyphicons, and got a bunch of files. I copied all these missing files into my fonts folder for site, where they were supposed to be, then uploaded them to site. After that, they worked.

I'd copied: glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf, glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg, glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot, glyphicons.yml, and bs-glyphicons-data-generator.js.

It may have been just the last file that was needed. If anyone cares to research it out and find out what works for all browsers, I'd be interested to know.